# How can I solve this flow error problem while declaring this.props

Tags: reactjs, flowtype

I have this code

```
export default class CompanyDetails extends React.Component<{}, State> {
  state = {
    profile: {
      name: { value: '', isRequired: true, hasError: false, order: 1 },
      industry: { value: '', isRequired: false, hasError: false, order: 2 },
      address: { value: '', isRequired: false, hasError: false, order: 3 },
      crn: { value: '', isRequired: true, hasError: false, order: 4 },
      website: { value: '', isRequired: false, hasError: false, order: 5 },
      employeesNbr: { value: '', isRequired: true, hasError: false, order: 6 },
      phoneNumber: { value: '', isRequired: true, hasError: false, order: 7 },
      userRole: { value: '', isRequired: true, hasError: false, order: 8 },
      personCheck: {
        value: false,
        isRequired: true,
        hasError: false,
        order: 9,
      },
    },
    showModal: {
      modal: { error: false },
    },
    buttonIsValid: {
      buttonIsValid: { isButtonValid: false },
    },
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.onRef(this);
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.props.onRef(undefined);
  }

  handleInputChange = (key: string, value: string) => {
    const { profile } = this.state;
    profile[key].value = value;
    profile[key].hasError = false;
    this.setState({ profile });
    this.handleIsButtonValid();
  };
```

How can I define type of this.props.ref, because yarn flow gives me this error

```
Cannot call `this.props.onRef` because property `onRef` is missing in object type [1].       

   src/containers/company-details.jsx:64:5
   64|     this.props.onRef(this);
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I am not able to find the proper way to do it. I tried declaring directly as a prop but also that didnt work

Answer (score 0):

Currently you're not defining props' shape (using `{}` in `React.Component<{}, State>`). So just define the type for `Props` and use it:

```
type Props = {
  onRef: (CompanyDetails | void) => void,
}

export default class CompanyDetails extends React.Component<Props, State> {
  // ...

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.onRef(this);
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.props.onRef(undefined);
  }
}
```

[Playground](https://flow.org/try/#0JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4AocmATzCTgAUcwBnOAXjgG9y44IAdskwAuOAAoAwrjAoB1ACJIYKYABs2AHzgA3CMAAmASg4A+XfoMAacgF9KSAB6RYcA0kwoArmvho1KCxs0uByisqqGnBOMEgCBmzI6DAAdCGQAnEwADxMEKzmPHxoMoJZCoYAshBeAjDiJkV8cDAAFsAsKWDMnYLC4m0dRhR89sWlmXUA6upqAKoCIDV1Ddy8zYOd3fm9Qh7ite6YwJnGI3D2tkA)

[Docs](https://flow.org/en/docs/react/components/) on adding Flow types to React components